# Azure Power Shell - How to change network subnet

Tags: powershell, azure, networking

I'm trying to change an existing VM deployed via Resource Manager in Azure. The VM is configured with a wrong VirtualNetwork / Subnet. Changing this via `portal.azure.net` is not possible.

I've managed to retrieve the required network adapter by running: `$adapter = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name xxxxx -ResourceGroupName xxxxx`.

I can see the current configured subnet id via `$adapter.IpConfigurations.Subnet` and I've retrieved the new subnet via `$net = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName xxxxx -Name xxxxx`.

I tried changing the `$net.IpConfigurations.Subnet.Id = $net.Subnets.Id` but I get a failure :

> Subnet default referenced by resource xxxx is not the same Virtual
>   Network ....

Can anybody tell me how to change the virtual network that a network adapter is using if it was deployed using **Resource Manager** (the "Classic" has the simple `Set-Subnet` command).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the Virtual Network for an exiting ARM deployed VM is not possible. But, changing the subnet for a VM is quite easy.

1. Login the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com)
2. In **Resource groups**, choose the resource group your VM is in.
3. Choose your VM in the resources list of your resource group.
4. in **Setting** blade of your VM, and choose **Network Interfaces**.
   [image]
5. Select the network interface you want to change, and click **IP Address**.
   [image]
6. Choose a Subnet, and specify an IP address, or choose **Dynamic** Assignment.
   [image]
7. If none of the exiting subnets meets your requirement, click your Virtual network to create a new subnet.
   [image]

If you really want to change the Virtual Network of your VM, you can backup your OS Disk, and create a new VM with the OS Disk, and of course with the desired Virtual Network.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I need to change the Virtual Network, so I guess I'll need to tear down the instance.

Comment: Very nicely explained.